# Accessing to UWP in a private company ADFS system.

Tags: uwp, adfs

I am trying to log in into a ADFS system of my company. This ADFS does not support Azure Active Directory. I am trying to log in with UWP. I have tried with [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAccountManagement#known-issues) but I do not know if its correct or not. My aim is to get finally a SessionID from the web "behind" the ADFS.

Comment: There are similar posts without solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159834/how-to-authenticate-uwp-app-using-current-windows-loggedin-user)

Answer (score 1):

UWP is a native device.

For that you need ADAL.

This implies you need ADFS 4.0 which has full OpenID Connect / OAuth suport.

If all you want is web API, ADFS 3.0 may suit?

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-wam) and [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/).